# Adding height from xyz-layer to points in Vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, elevation, vector-layer

My task is to put the height from a DGM1 model in Germany to some points on an other vector layer with attribute table. I don't know how this possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A colleague showed me the ["Sample raster values"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#sample-raster-values) Function. Works perfectly.

[image: Rasterwerte abtasten]

Answer (score 1):

Use this expression to calculate the elevation at each point: `raster_value( 'raster',1,$geometry)`. Replace `'raster'` with the name of your raster layer and make sure both layers are in the same CRS.

*Use the expression in [field calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?#using-the-field-calculator) to create a new attribute or (as I did on the screenshot) in the label field to create a dynamic label:*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [Drape](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#drape-set-z-value-from-raster):

> Uses values sampled from a band within a raster layer to set the Z
> value for every overlapping vertex in the feature geometry.